# Vacuum dessication of MSL components?

Tags: reflow, humidity, sensitivity

The standard method of removing moisture from [MSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moisture_sensitivity_level)-sensitive SMD components prior to reflow is to bake in an oven for 12 hours or more. Without baking, there is a possibility of [popcorning](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74750/what-kind-of-failure-would-i-see-in-moisture-sensitive-parts/74752#74752), as the absorbed moisture expands rapidly (as steam) leading to high pressure and mechanical failure. Ranier Dudek explains popcorning [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-85729-236-0_14#page-1) and ISU.edu hosts a failure-mode paper showing actual cases [here](http://www.isu.edu.tw/upload/81201/48/news/postfile_22447.pdf).

But ovens require a lot of power and time to remove this moisture. Could an alternative be vacuum dessication?

[image: Vacuum pump and dessicating chamber]

A vacuum pump would still boil the moisture away, but without the large pressures of steam, correct? And once evacuated, the vessel could sit *unpowered* for days if needed, saving energy.

Is this viable for SMD components? I see where [vacuum storage and packaging](http://www.proteaninbound.com/totech/eDM-Super-Dry-MSD/2014-Catalog-Super-Dry.pdf) is utilized for SMD, but not *vacuum dessication* itself.

Comment: The time is so that the water turns into vapor *gently*, while a vacuum pump will vaporize it *quickly*.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - that would depend on the pressure, just like baking depends on the temperature.  In raising the temperature you are raising the vapor pressure of water a bit above the ambient pressure, lowering the ambient pressure could also achieve the same difference.